# Is my SSD dead/corrupted? Or it is windows?

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-11, bsod

I use an NVMe SSD for my OS instalion, windows 11, and an HD for data and games

I left my computer turned on while i was eating, with the screen locked, when i got back the screen was not turning back on, was just black and would not show the login or anything, so i rebotted, windows 11 started it process of restore after a no clean shutdown, but got BSOD with "critical service error"

After trying to boot again not even BSOD, just stuck in the bios screen with the windows text about non clean shutdown, rebboted a third time to get in the repair screen, automatic repair failed, gone on advanced options, following this [instructions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/critical-service-failed/55fcbb60-b804-4819-9756-b85ef76010f4), but "DISM /Online" only wield an error "dism is not compatible with windows pe", and "chkdsk" would not work with C:, also trying reinstall option does not work at all either.

The only disk that seens to appear was disk "E:", which is my HD, but no signal of my SSD, i tried use diskpart, but only the HD would show there.

It is weird that the repair mode can't find the SSD, but it should be were it self is being loaded from(??), or does windows creates copies of the repair software on all disks?
Anyone has any idea what happened? And possible solutions?

Comment: I'd start by trying to confirm simillar behavior using a live environment (liveCD/USB) just to make sure its not a limitation of recovery console.

Comment: There's a serious risk that the SSD has failed.

Comment: Having seen same issue on my computer (not sure if you have laptop or desktop; mine was desktop), it may not be - though I agree with @harrymc it likely is - a hardware fail, but your SSD overheating. In my PC my NVMe SSD was directly under the GPU and when the room got hot and I taxed the system with heavy load I experienced same symptoms as you had. two or three times. This PC still uses same SSD, though I have less powerful GPU in it now, and see no issues. Or you Windows updated and corrupted your SSD...

Comment: @AcePL: I think that it's unlikely for a non-booting computer to be overheating.

Comment: @harrymc - I know, and I said as much. But I also know what I experienced, and setting aside the fact this makes it anecdotal, this may provide some insight for the OP. However, having said all that above, I just thought of something: maybe it wasn't SSD overheating (however, monitor was reporting the NVMe temps in excess of 58 degrees Celsius when in use), but power requirements. Curiously, the NVMe disconnecting and causing crash is not unheard of if the system has more than one drive. Most often reported fix is PSU replacement or cabling replacement (as well as removing extension cables).

Comment: @harrymc 2/2 - ....because in my case after leaving PC powered down for some time, when turned back on after 2-3 hours or after night, it would start and boot as if nothing happened. When my NVMe disappeared from PC, immediate restart would not help. It would power on, but drive would not be recognized in BIOS and thus it would not boot. But, as said above, wait some time and when turned of PC would work literally as if nothing happened.